# React native iOS devices different layouts. How to let them look the right way?

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, layout, mobile-devices

I wanted to build a Login Screen but the Loginbutton had different positions on the different devices. I seems like the login box also has not always 30% distance to the top but I am not sure.
I used EStyleSheet for distances in percent.
Please help I don't know how to fix this.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
  Switch,
  Image,
  SafeAreaView
} from 'react-native';
import EStyleSheet from 'react-native-extended-stylesheet';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
const util = require('util');

EStyleSheet.build({
  $textColor: 'white'
});

export default class loginScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isActive: true }
  }
  static navigationOptions = {
      title: 'Login',
      header: null,
  };
  render() {
      var {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{height: '100%',width: '100%',alignItems:'center'}}>
        <Text style={styles.loginText}>Thats the first line of text!</Text>
        <View style={styles.loginView}>
        <View style={{width: '100%', height: 8, backgroundColor: 'red',}}></View>
        <Text style={styles.loginViewText}>LOGIN</Text>
        <View style={{top: '35%',}} >
        <TextInput style={styles.emailfield} underlineColorAndroid="transparent" placeholder="E-mail" />
        <TextInput style={styles.passwordfield} underlineColorAndroid="transparent" secureTextEntry={true} placeholder="Passwort" />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.rememberView} ><Switch style={styles.switch} value={this.state.isActive} onValueChange={(val) => this.setState({isActive: val})}/>
        <Text style={styles.rememberMe}>Remember me</Text></View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.ButtonView} pointerEvents='box-none'>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.loginScreenButton}
          onPress={() => navigate('Second', {})}>
          <Image style={{width: 80, height: 80, }} source={require("../assets/LoginButton.png")}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.createAcc}></View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = EStyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  loginScreenButton:{
    position: 'absolute',
    right: '5%',
    bottom: '25%',
    shadowColor: '#000000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 15 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 18,
    elevation: 2,
  },
  loginText:{
    textAlign:'center',
    width: 350,
    top: '20%',
    fontSize: 36,
  },
  passwordfield:{
    width: 200,
    fontSize: 18,
    borderBottomColor: 'grey',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    marginTop: 30,
  },
  emailfield:{
    width: 200,
    fontSize: 18,
    borderBottomColor: 'grey',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
  },
  loginView:{
    top: '30%',
    height: '30%',
    minHeight: 250,
    width: 300,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    shadowColor: '#000000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 15 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 18,
    elevation: 2,
    borderRadius: 8,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  loginViewText:{
    fontSize: 30,
    left: '8%',
    top: '8%',
    position: 'absolute',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  rememberMe:{
    position: 'absolute',
    left: '30%',
  },
  switch:{
    left: '8%',
    position: 'absolute',
  },
  rememberView:{
    width: 300,
    height: 50,
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  createAcc:{
    shadowColor: '#000000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 15 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 18,
    elevation: 2,
  },
  ButtonView:{
    height: '30%',
    minHeight: 250,
    width: 300,
    alignItems: 'center',
  }
});
```

[Iphone 5s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzplw.png)

[Iphone X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrdUz.png)

Comment: Always try to use flexbox to maintain your styles. Also don’t use specified width and height values. Use percentages and rem for fontSizes. (You can find how to set rem value in their guide)

Comment: Thank you I fixed it now but the percentage doesn't work for the email field and the password field